# What would the equation $x=0$ look like in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

What would the equation $x=0$ look like in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

My intuition is that given the standard equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is $ax+by+cz=d$ and so if $x=0$ then there are infinitely many values $(0,y,z)$, for $y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ which would satisfy the equation above.

Is this correct? Is there a way I would  be able to graph this on the computer?

If the context is not given, how would you know that $x=0$ represents an equation of a plane? Could i not say that there are infinitely many values which would satisfy the equation $ax+by^2+cz^3=d$, where $x=0$? Not sure if what i have said makes any sense. $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 3):

$0=x=x+0y+0z$, so as you have noticed, this is a plane with normal $(1,0,0)$. More specifically, it is the $y-z$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

$x=0$ in a vector space would mean a vector equation, so
$$
x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \cr x_2 \cr \vdots \cr x_n \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 0 \cr \vdots \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}=0.
$$